# Adding Interface to Already Declared Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extend

I have a date utility tries to manage multiple date formats from external libraries that looks something like this.

```
import GoogleDateType;
import JodaDateType;
import ProtoDateType;

// Simple conversion to milliseconds for each date type.
public static Long toMillis(GoogleDateType date) {
  return date.getMillis(); 
}

public static Long toMillis(JodaDateType date) {
  return date.getMillisFromEpoch()
}

public static Long toMillis(ProtoDateType date) {
  return date.getSeconds() * 1000;
}

// Convert from date to date.
public static GoogleDateType toGoogleDateType(JodaDateType date) {
  return new GoogleDateType(toMillis(date));
}

public static GoogleDateType toGoogleDateType(ProtoDateType date) {
  return new GoogleDateType(toMillis(date));
}

// Lots more date conversions from type A to B, B to A, etc.
...
```

I'd hope to actually reduce the overall cost of writing all this out by  by giving each date an implementation of toMillis. Then I can just write one conversion from the interface to the type like this.

```
import GoogleDateType;
import JodaDateType;
import ProtoDateType;
import MillisConversion

// Simple conversion to milliseconds for each date type.
public static Long toMillis(GoogleDateType date) implements MillisConversion<GoogleDateType> {
  return date.getMillis(); 
}

public static Long toMillis(JodaDateType date) implements MillisConversion<JodaDateType> {
  return date.getMillisFromEpoch()
}

public static Long toMillis(ProtoDateType date) implements MillisConversion<ProtoDateType> {
  return date.getSeconds() * 1000;
}

// Just need one function now to convert anything to GoogleDateType.
public static GoogleDateType toGoogleDateType(MillisConversion date) {
  return new GoogleDateType(toMillis(date));
}
```

Forgive the ugly pseudo-code but anything I can do to build some logical pattern like this that'll allow me to build logic into existing classes to group them in a similar way and still maintain a strongly typed parameter list?

Comment: You should look into the adapter pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add new methods or variables to already-initialized classes. you can copy a class as a variable to your custom class, but that's pretty messy.

but I think the real issue you have is that you get exponentially more possibilities for each date type

so to keep it linear, all you need is

```
public long toMillis (GoogleDateType date){
    return date.getMillis()
}
...
```

and

```
public GoogleDateType googleMillis (long millis){
    return new GoogleDateType(millis);
}
...
```

and then you can

```
GoogleDateType g = googleMillis (toMillis(someJodaDateType));
```